# python csv writer with tweepy streaming

Tags: python, csv, twitter

Today I decided that I would like to export the twitter stream into a CSV file. However, I seem to not get it to work. Process finished with exit code 0 - so the error code doesn't provide me any info.

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import json
import time
from textblob import TextBlob
import csv

# consumer key, consumer secret, access token, access secret.
from streamertest_config import *


class StdOutlistener(StreamListener):

    def on_connect(self):
        print("Connected to streaming API")

    def on_data(self, data):
        all_data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = TextBlob(all_data["text"])
        tweet_id = all_data(["id"])

        # Adding polarity and subjectivity as separated values
        tweet_pol = tweet.sentiment.polarity
        tweet_sub = tweet.sentiment.subjectivity

        time.sleep(0.1)

        print(tweet)
        print(tweet_pol)
        print(tweet_sub)

        with open('tweets.csv', 'a') as tf:
            writer =csv.writer(tf)
            tf.write('\n')
            writer.writerow(["tweet", "tweet_id", "tweet_pol", "tweet_sub"])
            writer.writerows([tweet, tweet_id, tweet_pol, tweet_sub])
        return True

# Parsing the api user credentials
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)


# Starting the search. In case of error try again

def start_stream():
    while True:
        try:
                twitter_stream = Stream(auth, StdOutlistener())
                twitter_stream.filter(track=["Trump"], languages=["en"])
        except:
            return
start_stream()
#except Exception as e:
#print("[!] Error: %s" % e)
#return
```

Before I used the JSON format and exported all the data which worked fine. 
However, this time I want to export some specific fields (the tweet, tweet id, tweet_pol, tweet_sub).

Can somebody explain to me how I'm supposed to code this? And, perhaps you can recommend me a book which can help me with these basic tasks?

**EDIT: it is partially working now. The code above writes one CSV row. 
However, the tweet text is separated with a lot of commas.** 
Example output: "@,s,c,o,r,k,r,e,n, ,@,W,a,t,c,h,O,u,t,f,o,r,L,u,c,y, ,@,b,l,a,k,e,m,s,u, ,@,"

Second it stops working after the first tweet. At last, the tweet_pol and tweet_sub aren't passed through the csv writer. Any further suggestions on how I can improve it? 
I appreciate any effort! !

Kind regards

Comment: `writerow` not `writerows`.  `writerows` requires a list of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example you can adapt.  Your option to use `utf8` or `utf-8-sig` encoding.  UTF-8 allows any Unicode characters to be encoded to the CSV.  The latter encoding provides an initial BOM character that helps some tools like Excel read the CSV properly.  `newline=''` is documented to be used with `csv.writer` when opening the file.

```
#coding:utf8
import csv

def setup():
    '''Open and truncate file.  Write header.
    '''
    with open('tweets.csv','w',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as tf:
        writer = csv.writer(tf)
        writer.writerow(["tweet","tweet_id","tweet_pol","tweet_sub"])

def write(tweet,tweet_id,tweet_pol,tweet_sub):
    with open('tweets.csv','a',encoding='utf-8-sig',newline='') as tf:
        writer = csv.writer(tf)
        writer.writerow([tweet,tweet_id,tweet_pol,tweet_sub])

setup()
write('中文tweet',1,'something','something else')
write('Español tweet',2,'something','something else')
```

Output:

```
tweet,tweet_id,tweet_pol,tweet_sub
中文tweet,1,something,something else
Español tweet,2,something,something else
```